# Find the subfolders by folder ID and read the files in ELO

Tags: c#

This should be done in C #

My ELO hierarchy looks like this.
[image]

---

The folder FOLDER2 contains a text document. This is searched for and the object ID is returned. From this I get also the object ID "1234" for the FOLDER2.
[image]

---

Now there is in the folder TEXTFILES important text documents I would like to download.
[image]

Now to my question, if I have the object ID of FOLDER2, how can I find out which object ID of the folder TEXTFILES has to read out all data or download it there?

```
EditInfo ed = conn.Ix.checkoutDoc(pObjID, pDocID, EditInfoC.mbDocument, LockC.NO);
                DocVersion dv = ed.document.docs[0];
                String outFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + "." + dv.ext;
                conn.Download(dv.url, outFile);
                String url = dv.url;
```

Here is the code on how to download a file. There are the methods `dv.relativeFilePath`, `dv.physPath` so I could read the path to end up simply ELO / FOLDER1 / FOLDER2 / **TEXTFILES** could attach to the path to download the files

Comment: This question is missing an important link: everyone would talk about files in terms of a path and filename, but you talk about object IDs. Can you please explain how ID and path of a file are related?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find any official public documentation on your `ELO` API. I even not sure what the `ELO` stands for except that there is an "Indexserver Programming Guide" e-book offered at https://www.elo.com/wcm/en/service/elo-e-books If you can provide such a link, we (the SO community) probably will be able to answer your question better.

The only API reference I found that seems to match your short code example is Java API (unoficially) published at http://datigapowa.free.fr/javadoc8.00.036/. I assume that C# API is quite similar to the Java one described there and it looks like your `conn.Ix` is of type that matches for `IXServicePortIF` class as described at http://datigapowa.free.fr/javadoc8.00.036/de/elo/ix/client/IXServicePortIF.html. At least according to http://datigapowa.free.fr/javadoc8.00.036/index-all.html this is the only class that has `checkoutDoc(ClientInfo, String, String, EditInfoZ, LockZ)` method.

So looking into `IXServicePortIF` you may find interesting methods [`findFirstSords(ClientInfo ci, FindInfo findInfo, int max, SordZ sordZ)`](http://datigapowa.free.fr/javadoc8.00.036/de/elo/ix/client/IXServicePortIF.html#findFirstSords(de.elo.ix.client.ClientInfo,%20de.elo.ix.client.FindInfo,%20int,%20de.elo.ix.client.SordZ)), `findNextSords(ClientInfo ci, java.lang.String searchId, int idx, int max, SordZ sordZ)` and mysterious `processFindResult(ClientInfo ci, java.lang.String searchId, ProcessInfo procInfo)`. The `findFirstSords` accepts a parameter of [`FindInfo`](http://datigapowa.free.fr/javadoc8.00.036/de/elo/ix/client/FindInfo.html) class which in turn has a parameter of [`FindChildren`](http://datigapowa.free.fr/javadoc8.00.036/de/elo/ix/client/FindChildren.html) class and it seems to be responsible for search through folders.

On the other hand, return value of the `findFirstSords` is [`FindResult`](http://datigapowa.free.fr/javadoc8.00.036/de/elo/ix/client/FindResult.html) which contains

- a collection of plain string `ids`
- a collection of [`Sord`](http://datigapowa.free.fr/javadoc8.00.036/de/elo/ix/client/Sord.html) which in turn features a few potentially interestings "IDs" such as just `id` and `doc`

some of which is might be what you need.

Note also that "See also" section of `findFirstSords` documentation references some examples including C# one called [FindChildren.cs.txt](http://datigapowa.free.fr/javadoc8.00.036/src/FindChildren.cs.txt)

Hope this helps.